# How to conditionally enable/disable a table rows on click() in html using css

Tags: html, css, angular

My code:

component class:

```js
this.locknumbers = true;
onclick(){
this.locknumbers = false;
}
```

```css
.disabledRows {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    cursor: default;
}
```

```
[ngClass]= "{'disableRows':locknumber}".

<a  (click)="onClick()"> Enable </a>
```

Initially it is disabled but when I click on enabled button, the contents are still disabled but in console I can see the value of this. lock numbers changing to false; even though the style class is applied on click.

Comment: You have a typo in your template, you wrote `locknumber` instead of `locknumbers`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+disablerows+onclick+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 1):

There is typo also in css class name `disableRows` and `disabledRows`.

If you are using VSCode, checkout extension "Angular Language Service". It can detect variable names in angular components. It doesn't help in the CSS class name part, but it will catch the `locknumber` variable name and type in the template.

Your code should be fine after typos fixed.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use this code better for the toggle button

```
this.locknumbers = true;
onclick(){
this.locknumbers = !this.locknumbers
}
```